# node.js equivalent of python's if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: node.js

I'd like to check if my module is being included or run directly. How can I do this in node.js?

Comment: `isMain` coming soon to node.js near you :)

Comment: @DimaTisnek Source or any more info on `isMain`? It sounds fantastic but I can't find anything about it

Comment: The only significant reference I can find is in [a Gist from CJ Silveiro](https://gist.github.com/ceejbot/b49f8789b2ab6b09548ccb72813a1054) describing NPM's proposal/vision for ESM modules in Node. I haven't been able to find anything official from Node.js themselves. Any links would be appreciated

Comment: https://exploringjs.com/nodejs-shell-scripting/ch_nodejs-path.html#detecting-if-module-is-main detecting if the current module is “main” (the app entry point)

Answer (score 475, accepted):

[The nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#accessing-the-main-module) describe another way to do this which may be the preferred method:

> When a file is run directly from Node, require.main is set to its module.

To take advantage of this, check if this module is the main module and, if so, call your main code:

```
function myMain() {
    // main code
}

if (require.main === module) {
    myMain();
}
```

EDIT: If you use this code in a browser, you will get a "Reference error" since "require" is not defined. To prevent this, use:

```
if (typeof require !== 'undefined' && require.main === module) {
    myMain();
}
```

Comment: you always have to check require.main === module **irrespective** of your function name.  
To make it clear above code should be modified as:

`var fnName = function(){
    // code
}

if (require.main === module) {
    fnName();
}`

Comment: I would wrap it with try...catch for browser compatibility

Comment: @OhadCohen "try...catch" might also catch real errors. I think it is better to just check if typeof require != 'undefined'.

Comment: But what if the file is forked?

Comment: Sadly this feature is gone with `--experimental-modules`.

Comment: @seamlik in this case, the package [es-main](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-main) can be used. Usage: `esMain(import.meta)` returns true iff the file is not imported.

Comment: For the deno users that came here https://deno.land/manual@v1.0.0/examples/testing_if_main

Answer (score 69):

```
if (!module.parent) {
  // this is the main module
} else {
  // we were require()d from somewhere else
}
```

EDIT: If you use this code in a browser, you will get a "Reference error" since "module" is not defined. To prevent this, use:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && !module.parent) {
  // this is the main module
} else {
  // we were require()d from somewhere else or from a browser
}
```

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Nope, but it's used in one of [node.js's tests](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/test/simple/test-cli-eval.js)

Comment: To me this reads better than the accepted answer and has the benefit of not requiring the module's "name"

Comment: the accepted answer doesn't use the module's name either.

Comment: this is deprecated. use `module.main` now

Comment: @pcnate Could you consider adding another answer to explain how to use `module.main`?