# Can I know, in node.js, if my script is being run directly or being loaded by another script?

Tags: node.js, module

I'm just getting started with node.js and I have some experience with Python. In Python I could check whether the `__name__` variable was set to `"__main__"`, and if it was I'd know that my script was being run directly. In that case I could run test code or make use of the module directly in other ways.

Is there anything similar in node.js?

Comment: possible duplicate of [node.js equivalent of python's if \_\_name\_\_ == '\_\_main\_\_'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981891/node-js-equivalent-of-pythons-if-name-main)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The accepted answer is fine.  I'm adding this one from [the official documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module) for completeness:

## Accessing the main module

When a file is run directly from Node, `require.main` is set to its `module`. That means that you can determine whether a file has been run directly by testing

```
require.main === module
```

For a file `"foo.js"`, this will be `true` if run via `node foo.js`, but `false` if run by `require('./foo')`.

Because `module` provides a `filename` property (normally equivalent to `__filename`), the entry point of the current application can be obtained by checking `require.main.filename`.

Comment: The accepted answer is now deprecated so this is now the best one

Answer (score 99):

You can use `module.parent` to determine if the current script is loaded by another script.

e.g.

`a.js`:

```
if (!module.parent) {
    console.log("I'm parent");
} else {
    console.log("I'm child");
}
```

`b.js`:

```
require('./a')
```

run `node a.js` will output:

```
I'm parent
```

run `node b.js` will output:

```
I'm child
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Also looks much cleaner than Python

Comment: You can also use `module.main` which is similar

Comment: @Raynos I think you mean `require.main === module` (the official recommendation on http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but checking `module.parent` seems more intuitive than comparing `require.main` to `module`.

Comment: Just FYI, `module.parent` is deprecated as of Node 14.6.0 — see https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0144. Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311382/398713 says, checking `require.main === module` is now the recommended method.

Answer (score 11):

Both options `!module.parent` and `require.main === module` work.
If you are interested in more details please read [my detailed blog post about this topic](http://thlorenz.com/blog/how-to-detect-if-a-nodejs-module-is-run-as-a-script/).

Comment: Thanks for noticing, fixed the link.

Comment: Just FYI, `module.parent` is deprecated as of Node 14.6.0 — see https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0144. Like https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311382/398713 says, checking `require.main === module` is now the recommended method.