# Can I know, in deno, if my script is being run directly or being loaded by another script?

Tags: deno

Parallel in node: [Can I know, in node.js, if my script is being run directly or being loaded by another script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864365/can-i-know-in-node-js-if-my-script-is-being-run-directly-or-being-loaded-by-an)

I am looking for a way to tell if a deno script is being run direcly or if it's being imported by another module. Is this possible in deno? If so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `import.meta.main` to know if a script is the entry point or not.

**main.js**

```
import child from './child.js';

console.log('Main', import.meta.main);
```

**child.js**

```
export default 'foo';
console.log('child', import.meta.main);
```

Now when you execute:

```
deno run main.js
```

You'll get:

```
child: false
Main: true
```