# How can my Node script detect whether it is being called by `require`?

Tags: node.js, reflection

If your code detects that it is called by `require`, you may want it to branch accordingly, doing or not doing certain things in each case.  How do I do this?

Comment: Not entirely sure why you would want to do this. If you could explain what you are trying to do, that may help.

Comment: When I am writing some code which will be used in another script, I usually write some tests in the same file. But After finished, that code should be removed or commented. I don't like that. So I want to know if there's friendly way to hide it, with kepping it in the same file.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981891/node-js-equivalent-of-pythons-if-name-main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just check if `module.parent` is not `null` or `undefined`. If it is set with an object, then your module is being called with `require`.