# `if __name__ == '__main__'` equivalent in javascript es6 modules

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to check if JavaScript file is being run directly or if it was required as part of an es6 module import.

for example a main script is included.

```
// main.js
import './other';

if (mainTest){
  console.log('This should run');
}
```

which imports a dependency.

```
// other.js
if (mainTest){
  console.log('This should never run');
}
```

including `<script src=main.js></script>` should result in the console message from `main.js` but not other.js.

I found the [answer to this question with regards to node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981891/node-js-equivalent-of-pythons-if-name-main), but I am interested specifically for es6 imports

Comment: No, ES6 modules do not make this information available.

Comment: The specification is a work in progress. So we don't know yet what the final code to retrieve this information looks like.

Comment: See also [Detect whether ES Module is run from command line in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57838022/1048572)

Answer (score 21):

An alternative for ES6 modules is [now supported](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_import_meta) in Node. Using the new `import.meta` builtin. (Don't forget to set [`"type": "module"`](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packagejson-and-file-extensions) in `package.json`.)

#### Example

```js
// main.js
import "./lib.js"
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

if (process.argv[1] === fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)) {
  console.log("I print to stdout!");
}
```

```js
// lib.js
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

if (process.argv[1] === fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)) {
  console.log("I don't run, because I'm an imported module.");
}
```

`$ node main.js` output:

```
I print to stdout!
```

#### Utility function

I like to just `import { isMain } from "./lib/utils.js"` and pass `import.meta.url` to `isMain()`.

````js
import { argv } from "process"
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"
/**
 * Check if a module is the main module launched with the node process.
 * Meaning the module is NOT imported by another module,
 * but was directly invoked by `node`, like this: `$ node main.js`
 *
 * @example
 * ```js
 * // main.js
 * import lib from "./lib.js"
 * import { isMain } from "./utils.js"
 *
 * if (isMain(import.meta.url)) {
 *   console.log("I print to stdout")
 * }
 *
 * // lib.js
 * import { isMain } from "./utils"
 *
 * if (isMain(import.meta.url)) {
 *   console.log("I don't run, because I'm an imported module")
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * @param {string} moduleUrl needs to be `import.meta.url`
 * @returns {boolean} true if the module is the main module
 */
export function isMain(moduleUrl) {
  const modulePath = fileURLToPath(moduleUrl)
  const [_binPath, mainScriptPath] = argv
  return modulePath === mainScriptPath
}
````

Answer (score 8):

[`module.parent`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v5.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_module_parent) will help you:

```
if(module.parent) {
    console.log('required module')
} else {
    console.log('main')
}
```

Comment: That seems to be node-specific as well.

Comment: Yes, ES6 modules don't add anything here. Also, I guess it can be emulated somehow with Webpack for browsers.

Comment: I'm looking for something that works in browsers. currently I use rollup as my bundling mechanism

Comment: NOTE: module.parent is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0144) now

Answer (score 2):

`module.parent` was deprecated in Node.js v14.6.0, however we can use `require.main`.

```js
function main() {
    console.log("You're running the main file!");
}

if (require.main === module) {
    main();
}
```

A related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45137096/9591441).

Comment: It only works with commonjs and not es6 modules.

Answer (score 1):

The following simple code is available.

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

if (__filename === process.argv[1]) {
  console.log("main");
} else {
  console.log("not main");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in Node.js with type module, and don't name your files the same, and don't want to import a library, and want 1 line of code, this'll work:

```js
if(process.argv[1].split('/')[process.argv[1].split('/').length - 1] === import.meta.url.split('/')[import.meta.url.split('/').length - 1]) {
  console.log("called from commandline")
} else {
  console.log("imported")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which works for both CommonJS and ES6. Read the code comments for example usage. This is written in TypeScript but can be easily converted to any flavor of plain JS.

````
// const { fileURLToPath } = require('url');
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";

/** 
 * Determines whether a module is the entry point for the running node process.
 * This works for both CommonJS and ES6 environments.
 * 
 * ### CommonJS
 * ```js
 * if (moduleIsEntry(module)) {
 *     console.log('WOO HOO!!!');
 * }
 * ``` 
 * 
 * ### ES6
 * ```js
 * if (moduleIsEntry(import.meta.url)) {
 *     console.log('WOO HOO!!!');
 * }
 * ```
 */
const moduleIsEntry = (moduleOrImportMetaUrl: NodeModule | string) => {
    if (typeof moduleOrImportMetaUrl === 'string') {
        return process.argv[1] === fileURLToPath(moduleOrImportMetaUrl);
    }

    if (typeof require !== 'undefined' && 'exports' in moduleOrImportMetaUrl) {
        return require.main === moduleOrImportMetaUrl;
    }

    return false;
}
````

Answer (score -1):

The solution I see there is just to define the variable in the script you're importing. I.e. you define `mainTest` in `main.js`, and then use your existing if block.