# Javascript module conditionally execute a function by the execution context environment

Tags: javascript

I write a module with some functions, and execute the functions in the module.

My object is:

If I run the module alone, those functions can be executed. But if it is imported by another function as a module, then those functions should not be executed.

Like the code as below for demonstration:

In the module, for example, moduleFunction.js:

```
function moduleFunction(){
  // some code run here
}
moduleFunction();  // run the function in standalone script, but not when import the module.
export default moduleFunction;
```

In another module, for example runModule.js:

```
import moduleFunction from "moduleFunction";
moduleFunction();
```

I already know I can achieve the task in Python by `if __name__ == "__main__":` .
Is there a way to get it done in JavaScript?

Comment: Looks like you can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34842738/if-name-main-equivalent-in-javascript-es6-modules