# Node.js, require.main === module

Tags: node.js

In Node.JS document, I found a sentence said

> When a file is run directly from Node.js, `require.main` is set to its
>   module. That means that it is possible to determine whether a file has been run directly by testing `require.main === module`.'

I want to ask what is the `main` here, I can not find definition of this `main` in source code, can anyone help, thanks!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`require` is a function.  `.main` is a property on that function so you can reference `require.main`.  That part of the doc you are referring to says that you can write code like this:

```
if (require.main === module) {
     // this module was run directly from the command line as in node xxx.js
} else {
     // this module was not run directly from the command line and probably loaded by something else
}
```

`module` in that above code is a variable that is passed to all modules that are loaded by node.js so that code basically says that if `require.main` is the current module, then the current module is what was loaded from the command line.

The code for setting that property is here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js#L44.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I cannot find the .main property in the Module.prototype.require in module.js file. I am just curious about where the source code define the .main property.

Comment: @jfriend00 The link to the code returns 404. Can you please update the link ? thanks

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira - Updated the link in the question.  Links like that are specific to a general organization of the nodejs code in Github and will change over time.  In this case, the module loading code was reorganized in the repository when code for the ES6 loader was added which is what caused this source file to get moved in the repository.

Comment: I understand, but thought this was important enough, and perceived that you have the in-depth knowledge of Node's source code in order to make it an easy task. I was correct in my assumptions. :) Thanks.

Comment: How to detect the same in es6 modules?

Comment: I added an [example below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60309682/524518) that shows an alternative to `process.main` when using ES modules with Node.js.

Answer (score 76):

When running [ECMAScript Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) with Node.js, `require.main` is not available.  As of Node 13.9.0, there is not a succinct way to determine whether a module was run directly or imported by another module.  It is possible that an `import.meta.main` value will allow for such a check in the future (comment on [the modules issue](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/274) if you think this makes sense).

As a workaround, it is possible to check if the current ES module was run directly by comparing the `import.meta.url` value to `process.argv[1]`.  For example:

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import process from 'process';

if (process.argv[1] === fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)) {
  // The script was run directly.
}
```

This does not handle the case where the script is called without the `.js` extension (e.g. `node script` instead of `node script.js`).  To handle this case, any extension could be trimmed from both `import.meta.url` and `process.argv[1]`.

The [`es-main` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-main) (caveat: I am the author) provides a way to check if an ES module is run directly, accounting for the different ways it can be run (with or without an extension).

```js
import esMain from 'es-main';

if (esMain(import.meta)) {
  // The script was run directly.
}
```

Comment: This information is surprisingly hard to find!

Comment: This failed for me when including an npm package from a relative path on the local hard drive. I believe there is a symbolic link involved, which causes `dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url))` to be different than `process.argv[1]`

Comment: is there an officially documented way to do this?  is it better to use `pathToFileURL` ro `fileURLtoPath`?

Answer (score 9):

Quite late me answer, but i leave it here for reference.

1. When a file is the entry point of a program, it's the main module.
   e.g. `node index.js OR npm start`, ​the `index.js` is the main module & the entry point of our application.
2. But we might  need to  run it just as a module, and NOT as a main module.  This can happen  if we  `require` the  `index.js`  like so:

`node -e "require('./index.js')(5,6)"`

We can check if a file is the main module in 2 ways.

1. `require.main === module`
2. `module.parent === null`

Lets say that we have a simple `index.js` file, that it either `console.log()` ,when it is the main module, or it exports a sum function, when it is not the main module:

```
if(require.main === module) {
 // it is the main entry point of the application
 // do some stuff here
 console.log('i m the entry point of the app')
} else{
 // its not the entry point of the app, and it behaves as 
 // a module
 module.exports = (num1, num2) => {
   console.log('--sum is:',num1+num2)
  }
 }
```

**Ways to check the above condition:**

1. `node index.js` --> will print `i m the entry point of the app`
2. `node -e "require('./index.js')(5,6)"` --> will print `--sum is: 11`

Answer (score 4):

For ECMAScript modules, or files with `.mjs` as its extension I use a simpler version of it:

```js
if (import.meta.url.endsWith(process.argv[1])) {
  // run the app
}
```