# Deprecated message: "Auto import from 'process' (property) NodeJS.Process.mainModule?: NodeJS.Module NodeJS.Module 'mainModule' is deprecatedts"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use mainModule like this:

```
const { mainModule } = require('process');
module.exports = path.dirname(mainModule.filename);
```

But I'm receiving the following messages:

> const mainModule: NodeJS.Module 'mainModule' is deprecatedts(6385)

> Auto import from 'process'
> (property) NodeJS.Process.mainModule?: NodeJS.Module

@deprecated — since v14.0.0 - use require.main instead.

How can I Solve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136831/node-js-require-main-module) that you just need to change this:

```
const { mainModule } = require('process');
module.exports = path.dirname(mainModule);
```

To this:

```
module.exports = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the lines given below

```
const path=require('path');
module.exports=path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since v14.0.0, mainModule is deprecated.
Now, you can achieve the same thing just by writing the following lines:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```