# How to publish [my own] npm package that can be invoked globally

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I've published a new public node app via npm. (Note: This is clearly an alpha. Don't expect very good, much less perfection.) I'm unable to get it work as a global install.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/khutzpa

To test, I installed it globally with this:

```
npm install -g khutzpa
```

On macOS, that installs in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa` for me.

I expected to be able to execute it at this point from the command line like this:

```
khutzpa /usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa/tests/fakeSite /openInBrowser
```

I cannot. When I run that line, I receive:

```
zsh: command not found: khutzpa
```

I have other packages installed globally that are found, including prettier and eslint.

If I run it via a full path to its index.js, it's happy and runs exactly like I'd expect.

```
node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa/index.js /usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa/tests/fakeSite /openInBrowser
```

That's the basic issue. Is there something additional I'm supposed to set up?

---

#### More info

##### index.js

I think all I need in package.json is the `main` entry, and I have that...

`"main": "index.js",`

You can see the `index.js` file [in full here](https://github.com/ruffin--/khutzpa/blob/main/index.js).

In that file, I'm doing a `if (require.main === module) {` check to see if it's used as a module, which [might be an issue now (?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60309682/1028230), but that doesn't seem to explain why it's not found at all.

##### npx

If I run with...

```
npx khutzpa /usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa/tests/fakeSite /openInBrowser
```

I receive...

```
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run
```

There's not a lot more info in the log it creates afaict.

```
34 verbose stack Error: could not determine executable to run
34 verbose stack     at getBinFromManifest (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/get-bin-from-manifest.js:17:23)
34 verbose stack     at exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpmexec/lib/index.js:114:15)
34 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:66:5)
35 verbose pkgid khutzpa@0.0.1-alpha
36 verbose cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/prettier
37 verbose Darwin 21.5.0
38 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "khutzpa" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa/tests/fakeSite" "/openInBrowser"
39 verbose node v16.15.0
40 verbose npm  v8.5.5
41 error could not determine executable to run
42 verbose exit 1
```

##### as a require in another package

Just tried invoking as an include, and it seems to work okay, except that I have to use `khutzpa.default` to invoke it, which I didn't think I needed to do. Maybe a hint. I'mma googling.

But I...

1. Created a dir.
2. `npm init -y`
3. On command line in that dir ran `npm install khutzpa`
4. Inserted this code:

```
const khutzpa = require("khutzpa");

console.log(khutzpa);
khutzpa.default("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa/tests/fakeSite", 3000, 1);
```

That works, though `khutzpa("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/khutzpa/tests/fakeSite", 3000, 1);` does not, so maybe an export issue?

Comment: It looks like I might need to learn about [package.json's `"bin"` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28440893/install-a-locally-developed-npm-package-globally) -- eg [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011384/1028230).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there may have been two issues:

I needed a "[sharp-exclamation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510581/1028230)" in my `index.js` file to let npm know where node is (?).

I needed [a `"bin"` entry in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54011384/1028230).

The best way to sum this is probably by pointing [at this commit that fixed things](https://github.com/ruffin--/khutzpa/commit/2c06dab7568ed2b53b00d3d64cab85fef91cf2cf).

Here's a summary in an image with a reasonably good alt description, I believe. I'll add some WinMerge reports in a bit:

[image: added #!/usr/bin/env node to first line of index.js and "bin": "index.js", to the package.json file, as well as incremented the version in package.json from "version": "0.0.1-alpha", to "version": "0.0.1-alpha.1",]