# detect whether ES Module is run from command line in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

When using CommonJS modules in Node, you can detect whether a script is being run from the command line using `require.main === module`.

What is an equivalent way to detect whether a script is being run from the command line when using ES Modules in Node (with the `--experimental-modules` flag)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use

```js
if (import.meta.url === `file://${process.argv[1]}`) {
  // module was not imported but called directly
}
```

See the [MDN docs on `import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta#using_import.meta) for details.

### Update Sep 27, 2021

Better to use [`pathToFileURL`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_pathtofileurl_path) which handles forward/backward slashes on Unix vs Windows correctly (via [Rich Harris](https://twitter.com/Rich_Harris/status/1355289863130673153))

```js
import { pathToFileURL } from 'url'

if (import.meta.url === pathToFileURL(process.argv[1]).href) {
  // module was not imported but called directly
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work on Windows due to the slashes.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers get close, but will miss the mark for a pretty typical usecase - cli scripts exposed by the `bin` property in `package.json` files.

These scripts will be symlinked in the `node_modules/.bin` folder. These can be invoked through `npx` or as scripts defined in the `scripts`-object in `package.json`. `process.argv[1]` will in that case be the symlink and not the actual file referenced by `import.meta.url`

Furthermore, we need to convert the file path to an actual `file://`-url otherwise it will not work correctly on different platforms.

```js
import { realpathSync } from "fs";
import { pathToFileURL } from "url";

function wasCalledAsScript() {
    // We use realpathSync to resolve symlinks, as cli scripts will often
    // be executed from symlinks in the `node_modules/.bin`-folder
    const realPath = realpathSync(process.argv[1]);

    // Convert the file-path to a file-url before comparing it
    const realPathAsUrl = pathToFileURL(realPath).href;
  
    return import.meta.url === realPathAsUrl;
}

if (wasCalledAsScript()) {
  // module was executed and not imported by another file.
}
```

I would have posted this as a comment on the accepted answer, but apparently I'm not allowed to comment with a fresh account.

Answer (score 6):

There is none - yet (it's still experimental!). Although the prevailing opinion is that such a check is a bad practice anyway and you should just provide separate scripts for the library and the executable, [there is an idea](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/274) to provide a boolean `import.meta.main` property for this purpose.

Comment: How about now? Is this still not possible?

Comment: This seems to work: ``if (import.meta.url === `file://${process.argv[1]}`) // module was not imported but called directly``.

Comment: @Casimir See the linked node issue thread. It's still not implemented, but there are workarounds.

Comment: @Casimir you should post your comment as an answer because that works and I'd guess it will always work.

Comment: @nicferrier Sure, posted this as an answer.

Comment: @Casimir alternatively, `import.meta.url === url.pathToFileURL(process.argv[1])` (via rich harris on twitter)

Comment: @forivall Thanks, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `module` global variable will be defined in CommonJS, but won’t exist at
all in an ES module. Yes, there is an inconsistency there, that ES modules are
the things that *don’t* have `module` variables.

You can check for an undefined variable by seeing if `typeof v` is the string
(not value!) `'undefined'`.

That turns into:

```
const inCommonJs = typeof module !== 'undefined';

console.log(`inCommonJs = ${inCommonJs}`);
```

If we put that exact code into both `.cjs` and `.mjs` files, we get the correct answers:

```
$ node foo.mjs
inCommonJs = false
$ cp foo.mjs foo.cjs
$ node foo.cjs
inCommonJs = true
```

Comment: Not sure how that helps... the question is how to detect, in an mjs, whether we have been called from the cli or imported from another module.

Answer (score 0):

I like `` import.meta.url === `file://${process.argv[1]}` `` , but it does not work in Windows inside bash shell. This is the alternative that is only checking the basename:

```
const runningAsScript = import.meta.url.endsWith(path.basename(process.argv[1]));
```

Answer (score -4):

It looks like there is a [documented way to do this now](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#accessing-the-main-module):

```
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log('executed directly');
    . . .
}
```