# Is Entry Point, ES6 Modules

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, es6-modules

In node, in order to determine if I'm in the entry file, the file referenced directly by node, I can use `__file__ === process.argv[1]`. `process.argv` is an array containing the arguments I used to call the `node` script. Therefore, the first `argv` is usually `node`, the second is the file I'm using. This is useful if I'm creating a library and I want to know whether I'm calling the library directly, for example for testing. This would typically get minified out in a production build.

How can I do the same thing in a browser? Before ES6 modules, all JavaScript files were effectively global, meaning the `<script>` tags were all called directly by the HTML. However, now, with ES6 modules, it is possible to import another JavaScript file. How do I determine whether I am in a file directly sourced by the browser, with `<script src="..."></script>`, or whether I am in a file that was imported by another script?

This could be useful for react components, especially in libraries. If I am in the "entry" file, I can `render` myself in a tag that I choose, perhaps `<main>`. If not, I can assume I'm being imported by another component, which will presumably render itself or be rendered in some other way. The same concept applies to other component-based libraries, like angular 2+, aurelia, etc. For example,

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

if(isEntryPoint()) {
    const main = document.querySelector('main');
    render(<App />, main);
}

function App() {
    return <div>Hello World!<div>;
}
```

So how do I find out if a file is directly referenced by the browser via `<script src="..."></script>`, or if it was imported by another JavaScript file? How should the `isEntryPoint` function look?

Comment: You cannot, and you should not. The established best practice is to provide two different modules, one "main" entry point and one library file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect whether ES Module is run from command line in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57838022/1048572)

Comment: This is nowhere near a duplicate. The other question is node, this one is in-beowser.

Comment: Oops, I mean to link the more generic [`if __name__ == '__main__'` equivalent in javascript es6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34842738/1048572).

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, this question is a closer dupe of that one. I still don't think it's an exact dupe, though, because that one isn't browser-specific, while this one is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there's any *reasonable* way for a browser-hosted module to know that it's been loaded directly rather than by another module. The *un*reasonable way I can think to do it is to compare the last segment of the URL in `import.meta.url` with the `script` elements present in the DOM and seeing if one matches.

I don't recommend it.

In fact, even then, if for some reason I have

```
<script type="module" src="./myfile.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./your-library.js"></script>
```

and `myfile.js` does:

```
import /* stuff */ from "./your-library.js";
```

That would make your library *think* it was loaded directly when it fact it was loaded via `myfile.js`.

So I *really* don't recommend it. ;-)

Instead, you're probably better off providing your library (`your-library.js`) with a setup call the code using it can use, and an optional additional module (`auto-your-library.js` or whatever) that A) loads your library, and B) does the setup call. (If you want to provide the automatic setup feature at all.)

Note: [`import.meta`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta) is new in ES2020.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of doing this. I was afraid it might take too long to compare all the `<script>` tags in the DOM, but it shouldn't be too bad. You're right, though, of course, in that it should only be done if you need to do it and have no other choice, at least until there's a standardized way to do it.

Comment: @trysis if you really want such behaviour of the library, the best practice would be to use `<script type="module" src="….mjs" data-autoload="true">` (or maybe specifiy the DOM selector of the element to load into, or something like that)

Comment: @trysis - Except for the `.mjs` part. :-)

Comment: `.mjs` indicates a module, it doesn't tell you which module is the entry point.

Comment: @trysis - My point was that `.mjs` is not widely-regarded as best practice. What identifies it as a module is `type="module"`. Browsers don't care about file extensions.

Comment: Would `import.parent` work, like in the answer to the question that @Bergi thought was a dupe?

Comment: @trysis - You mean `module.parent`? No, that's Node.js-specific.