# How do I detect if an ES Module is the main module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

How can I detect if an ECMAScript module is the main module? This is easy for CommonJS modules (see [Detect if called through require or directly by command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398196/detect-if-called-through-require-or-directly-by-command-line)).

- There is no `require` or `require.main`
- No `process.mainModule`
- The `import.meta` has no clues, only has `url`

Comment: What do you mean by main module? And in what context? browser? node.js?

Comment: take a look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57838022/detect-whether-es-module-is-run-from-command-line-in-node

Comment: @Luka The main module is the module directly invoked. It's node.js, as noted in the tags.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes: That sounds like a proper answer, not a comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [`if __name__ == '__main__'` equivalent in javascript es6 modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34842738/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`es-main`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es-main).

From the package README:

```js
import esMain from 'es-main';
 
if (esMain(import.meta)) {
  // Module run directly.
}
```

**NOTE**: This module will only work in a Node.JS environment, because the module code uses native Node.JS modules.

Comment: `es-main` [does](https://github.com/tschaub/es-main/blob/8a569c0ca2345221e62a1dedeb00f9a29301178f/main.js#L20) `fileURLToPath(import.meta.url) === process.argv[1]`, possibly stripping the extension from the module path if it's missing from the script name.

Answer (score 4):

In the browser I don't know, but in node with `.mjs` module the following seems to work :

```js
const isMainModule = import.meta.url.endsWith(process.argv[1])
```

Explanation:

`import.meta.url` begins with the protocole `file://` eg:

```sh
file:///path/to/my/module.mjs
```

but in node, process.argv[1] is shorter, eg:

```sh
/path/to/my/module.mjs
```

so `endsWith` is useful here.

Comment: I suspect this doesn't work if the path contains any characters that are quoted in URLs, and may not work on Windows at all.

Comment: Worked perfectly on linux with TypeScript + [@tsconfig/node16-strictest-esm/tsconfig.json](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases#node-16--esm--strictest-tsconfigjson) + `moduleResolution: "node"`.