# ES6 and values previously provided by the require object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In ES6 and later we prefer `import` over `require`.

In the absence of the `require` object, how does one access values historically presented as attributes of the require object? For example, `require.main.filename`

If there is a topic in the Node documentation dealing with this a reference would be greatly appreciated. In the meantime, I persist while Google fails to be my friend... obviously I'm asking the wrong question. Better search terms would also be helpful.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#importmeta is all there currently is

Comment: See also [Detect whether ES Module is run from command line in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57838022/1048572) for `.main` specifically

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans "*What happened to the properties of `require` in ES modules?*" is a perfectly valid question. Sure, there are [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64180480/1048572) for the particular use case, but nobody has asked the general question so far.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the timely, correct and actionable comment. Turn it into an answer so I can accept it before rule obsessed meddlers close this question.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that argument is also an argument for closing down Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing properties on the `require` function has been replaced by accessing the [`import.meta` object](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-meta#importmeta) in ES modules. It allows implementations to expose metadata about the module in a standard location.

Node.js in particular [currently supports](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#importmeta) `import.meta.url` (like CommonJS `__filename` and `__dirname`) and `import.meta.resolve` (like `require.resolve`). The [discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/274) about adding `import.meta.main` appears to have stalled.