# Making a function to return whether the current code is being run directly or being imported, without using eval

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848622/340947) it is possible for JS module code to determine whether it is being run directly or being imported from somewhere else. This is analogous to the [old way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398196/detect-if-called-through-require-or-directly-by-command-line) but module is not a thing anymore in the EcmaScript Modules world? Or is it?

So, I wanted to take it a step further and use this as an opportunity to learn a few things under the hood.

I tried this

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import url from "url";
const code = `
  console.error(
    "isScript debug: x:", import.meta.url, " y:", url.pathToFileURL(process.argv[1]).href
  );
  return import.meta.url === url.pathToFileURL(process.argv[1]).href;
`;
const f = Function(code);
export const isScript = () => f();
```

... as an attempt to not use `eval` which is "evil". Basically I want to be able to incorporate this logic in my scripts without having to write the `import.meta.url === url.pathToFileURL(process.argv[1]).href` code in each place that I need it. Because of two reasons, (1) it's just difficult to remember, and (2) making ridiculously tiny "libraries" is trendy with JS. But i realize that this may be challenging due to the "special" nature of `import`.

Indeed this code does not run: `SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module`

Is this a fool's errand? I could at least still make an `isScript` which has to receive an `import.meta.url` value, right? The thing is, that'd be a mildly ~leaky abstraction~ (not sure what term to use here) and rather unsatisfactory.

By the way, `eval` also does not work, the code "compiles" but when importing this module and trying to run it, I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module` from the importing code. I might be doing something silly though.

Comment: As indicated by error messages (and you've only had the first), the approach to producing an `isScript` function taken in the post is likely doomed - how would it ever have access to the `import.meta` object of a caller given modules operate in their own name space and do not create global variables. Could you elaborate (in the question please) on the concern "that'd be a mildly leaky abstraction and rather unsatisfactory"? Potentially a response to the concern may be the most effective solution to the issue raised..

Comment: I'm probably definitely using the wrong term when i refer to it as a "leaky abstraction". Will edit.