# Import a Node.js module function, without invoking it

Tags: node.js

I have a Node.js module with a function that is exported, and designed to be invoked when the script is run from the command line:

```
function init() {
  console.log('initializing');
}
init();

module.exports = { init };
```

I'd like to require / import the underlying method in another module, without evaluating init.  Unfortunately require seems to evaluate it:

```
> require('./test.js').init;
initializing
{ init: [Function: init] }
```

Is it possible to require this method, without evaluating it in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[How about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981891/node-js-equivalent-of-pythons-if-name-main) putting the part you need to run when the script is invoked from the command line inside a check for `require.main === module`?  That way, `init()` is only called if you're invoking that script using `node test.js`.  So:

```
function init() {
    console.log('initializing');
}

if (require.main === module) {
    init();
}

module.exports = { init };
```

It kind of answers your question backwards, but I think this might be close to what you're looking for.

You might want to keep an eye out for [changes to this feature](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21143) with regards to the `--experimental-modules` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is related to the fact that you invoke the `init` function yourself.
Just do not invoke it in the module which contains implementation instead invoke the function after requiring it inside any other module.

```
function init() {
  console.log('initializing');
}
// warning! do not call invoke init function here
// init()

module.exports = { init };
```

Comment: I specifically need to invoke it in this use-case

Comment: Mind expanding on the use-case?  As it stands there's no way to parse a module without parsing every statement and that includes the call to `init()`

Comment: In this case, it will be always invoked since it is located in a module global scope.

Answer (score 1):

This means that `init()` shouldn't be executed automatically, and there should be different entry points.

One entry point for programmatic use (`test.js`). Another one to be used as command-line executable (`test-cli.js`):

```
require('./test.js').init()
```

This is a common scenario for NPM packages. CLI entry point can be specified in package [`bin`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin).